# Access to the path Denied when uploading excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

When uploading an excel file I am receiving this error, can anyone help me?

> Access to the path
>   'C:\Data\IronElements\Upload\AUMData\20101202
>   031815.xlsx' is denied.  Description: An unhandled exception occurred during
>   the execution of the current web
>   request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error
>   and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   'C:\Data\IronElements\Upload\AUMData\20101202
>   031815.xlsx' is denied.
>
> ASP.NET is not authorized to access
>   the requested resource. Consider
>   granting access rights to the resource
>   to the ASP.NET request identity.
>   ASP.NET has a base process identity
>   (typically {MACHINE}\ASPNET on IIS 5
>   or Network Service on IIS 6) that is
>   used if the application is not
>   impersonating. If the application is
>   impersonating via , the identity
>   will be the anonymous user (typically
>   IUSR_MACHINENAME) or the authenticated
>   request user.
>
> To grant ASP.NET access to a file,
>   right-click the file in Explorer,
>   choose "Properties" and select the
>   Security tab. Click "Add" to add the
>   appropriate user or group. Highlight
>   the ASP.NET account, and check the
>   boxes for the desired access.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated
>   during the execution of the current
>   web request. Information regarding the
>   origin and location of the exception
>   can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.

My Code behind file has the following syntax

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
                string FileName = Convert.ToString(date.ToString("yyyyMMdd hhmmss"));
                Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Data\\IronElements\\Upload\\AUMData\\Schema");
                doesFileExists("C:\\Data\\IronElements\\Upload\\AUMData\\Schema");
                fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\Data\\IronElements\\Upload\\AUMData\\" + FileName + ".xlsx");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                string connectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLConnection"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection SqlConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

                try
                {
                    SqlConnect.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmdAssetUnderManagement = new SqlCommand("Exec_Insert_AUMAssetValue", SqlConnect);
                    cmdAssetUnderManagement.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmdAssetUnderManagement.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }


                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    SqlConnect.Close();
                }
                lblAUMTA.Visible = true;
                lblAUMTA.Text = "File Upload Completed";
            }
    private void doesFileExists(string p)
            {
                p = string.Concat(p, "\\AUMSchema.xlsx");
                if (!File.Exists(p))
                {
                    fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\\Data\\IronElements\\Upload\\AUMData\\Schema\\AUMSchema.xlsx");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure the folder C:\Data\IronElements\Upload\AUMData has NTFS write permission for the user in which context IIS executes. Also please make sure that the subfolders of C:\Data\IronElements\Upload inherits permissions from it's parent. To do this, click Advanced button from security tab -> Change permissions -> check Replace all child object permissions with inheritable permissions from this object -> Hit Ok

Comment: it does have the READ and Write permissions

Comment: Make sure it has permissions for the account the ASP.NET process is running under. Oh and also make sure it is running under the account you THINK it is.

Comment: OK, this is not a good idea but give it a try. Assign read/write to Everyone role for that folder and see what happens. The upload should work after that.

Comment: it did check that, its running under the account which i needed, i had been working on this issue for almost 2 days. tried all the possible ways by adding different accounts.

Comment: did assign read/write permissions to everyone but it still didnot work

Answer (score 1):

The account that your web session is running under does not have permissions to write to that folder. Once you give the ASP.Net account (or whichever account you are using) the required permissions, it should work as expected.

Comment: I made the folder to be accessed around the NETWORK SERVICE with full control and also made the folder as shared folder. but still it doesnot work

Answer (score 1):

go to the app-pool which you are using for this application and change the identity of it to 'Network Service'. I faced the similar issue and fixed in same way

Answer (score 0):

To get a better handle on permission problems like this I always create a low-priv'ed user to run our websites. The user is named after the website itself so it's obvious what it's for.

Then that user only gets perms on the right folders, in your case, C:\Data\IronElements\Upload\AUMData. It's also a good way to limit DB access - create a login for that specific user in SQL with minimal privs.